# Amend the texts (font) in llustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How to amend the texts (font) in Adobe illustrator?

**A** letter and I want to remove the Horizontal line.

So it would be like this:

[image]

Comment: You cannot edit fonts with Illustrator. For a once-operation: convert text to outlines.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the type into vector outlines using Cmd + Shift + O or from the menu use Type -> Create Outlines. Then you can edit the letter shapes as needed. But to actually create a new font from your work, you will need:

1. Permission from the original typeface owner (some type foundries are actually fairly permissive, others are... not). **Legal questions should be directed to a lawyer in your jurisdiction.**
2. Or your own letter shapes that were specifically generated by you and are not derivatives of copyrighted work. **Legal questions should be directed to a lawyer in your jurisdiction.**
3. A font editor like FontForge, FontLab or Glyphs to generate a font file in the format desired.

Comment: Could you update your answer, how to remove a Horizontal line from A?

Comment: "The usual way"? After converting to outlines, it's a path just like everything else in Illustrator. (And so it may be grouped and ungrouped, combined, edited, etc.)

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back - like Jongware notes, use Illustrator's tools to manipulate and edit the paths of the letter shapes. After the letters are converted to vector shapes, you can use a variety of tools (the pen tool, eraser tool, knife tool, scissors tool, and even the direct selection tool) to accomplish removing the bar of the "A" character. If you know how to create and remove points on a path in Illustrator, its the same idea.